# Send outgoing email from a wikibase docker container

Tags: wikibase

We've installed [wikibase-docker](https://github.com/wmde/wikibase-docker) with an Apache server in front of it to handle SSL and proxy two vhosts to the ports from Docker.

When I use the PasswordReset function it should sent out an email. But instead only `sh: 1: -t: not found` is logged by the wikibase container.

Answer (score 2):

After searching a bit I found the MediaWiki config option [$wgSMTP](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgSMTP) that can be added to LocalSettings.php in the wikibase container.

```
$wgSMTP = [
    'host'     => 'mail.example.com', // could also be an IP address. Where the SMTP server is located
    'IDHost'   => 'example.com',      // Generally this will be the domain name of your website (aka mywiki.org)
    'port'     => 25,                 // Port to use when connecting to the SMTP server
    'auth'     => true,               // Should we use SMTP authentication (true or false)
    'username' => 'my_user_name',     // Username to use for SMTP authentication (if being used)
    'password' => 'my_password'       // Password to use for SMTP authentication (if being used)
];
```

```
docker cp wikibase-docker_wikibase_1:/var/www/html/w/LocalSettings.php LocalSettings.php
edit LocalSettings.php
docker cp LocalSettings.php wikibase-docker_wikibase_1:/var/www/html/w/LocalSettings.php
```

Comment: Indeed, you need to configure email sending. The docs for that are at https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Email